# Docker Desktop Not Opening On Mac

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

The Docker Desktop icon flashes on the dock briefly and it doesn’t launch. It crashes silently without any error messages on the screen. The `com.docker.diagnose` tool is unable to diagnose from the terminal, the output of which has been attached below.

#### Output of `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.diagnose check`

```bash
➜  ~ /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.diagnose check
Starting diagnostics

[PASS] DD0027: is there available disk space on the host?
[SKIP] DD0028: is there available VM disk space?
[FAIL] DD0031: does the Docker API work? Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix://docker.raw.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
[1]    3128 killed     /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.diagnose check
```

#### Output of `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.diagnose gather --upload`

```bash
➜  ~ /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.diagnose gather --upload
Gathering diagnostics for ID 4DC1603E-1354-4CA3-BB31-4E0C839D67C2/20220819183640 into /var/folders/q1/9nwl1r8s4hgcp4q8_grx1kvmw56qkc/T/4DC1603E-1354-4CA3-BB31-4E0C839D67C2/20220819183640.zip.
This may take up to 15 minutes.
time="2022-08-20T00:06:40+05:30" level=info msg="Triggering Linux sysrq and log flushes via a unix socket: diagnosticd.sock" type=unixsock
time="2022-08-20T00:06:40+05:30" level=warning msg="/flush failed: Post \"http://unix/flush\": dial unix diagnosticd.sock: connect: no such file or directory" type=unixsock
[1]    3639 killed     /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.diagnose gather --upload
```

#### Information

- macOS Version: 12.2.1
- Intel chip or Apple chip: Intel
- Docker Desktop Version: 4.11.1

Comment: Same here, and other people having the same problem https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6456

Comment: @himmip yep, it's raised by me itself.

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem, I installed new version of docker and did the below. It worked for me.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker
rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker
rm -rf ~/.docker
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: on mac os, this worked

Comment: On macos, this worked but reset all of my settings and wiped my images. And sometimes that is a more acceptable path than restarting the computer (which has worked in the past).

Comment: This worked for me, Intel MacOS Ventura 13.0.1, Docker Desktop 4.18.0. Lost all my settings but at least it's running again.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I killed 'Docker' processes and restart Docker Desktop. I get back Docker Desktop launched.

1. Open 'Activities Monitor'
2. Filter processes listed on 'docker'keyword
3. Note the PID of the 2 'Docker' processes
4. From a terminal, kill those 2 processes : `kill pid` or `kill -9 pid`
5. Run Docker app

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the Mac solved the issue.

*[I tried to logout and login, but the restart only solved the issue.]*

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
**RESTART YOUR MAC.** This should solve your problem. (After installing Docker Desktop for Mac (https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/))

---

I was struggling with this for quite some time. I downloaded Docker Desktop for Mac (using Catalina OS 10.15.7), but after installation, I would try to open it and nothing would happen.

Let me clarify, On the first time opening the app (from Applications folder), it would ask me to "allow" the application, but on every other attempt, a Docker Desktop process would start, but no GUI would open and the tray icon wouldn't appear. After checking the Docker in Activity Monitor app, it would usually say "not responding".

After reading several articles and message boards, nothing helped. I finally decided to reset my Macbook Pro... wah-lah, problem solved. I don't know why the installation process doesn't prompt you to restart your Mac, but do it and it should solve your problem.